# Reviewer stats "button" does not appear as a button

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, user-interface

When an edit review is pending, the notification window includes what appears to be a link to see Reviewer Stats.

[image: a screenshot of the "you have already reviewed this item" popup]

On hovering, we can (barely) see that it's actually a button with a transparent background.

[image: the same screenshot but with the "reviewer stats" button hovered over]

Same thing occurs after an item has completed review, where we can see the difference with a properly coloured button:

[image]

I assume this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. It's an actual [Stacks button style](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/buttons/), so it's undoubtedly by-design. In fact, this is actually the *default* style for anything classed as a button. (You have to explicitly opt-in to either an outlined or filled style.) Whether it is sensible to have a button that doesn't look like a button except when you hover over it is debatable, like whether *most* of Stacks makes sense...

In *this specific case*, the design shouldn't have a button at all. This is a **progressive disclosure** idiom; it should use a flippy triangle or something that provides affordance to make the function clear. Unfortunately, Stacks strikes again; ["Expandable" components](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/expandable/) use toggle-buttons (i.e., things that look like buttons, but visually preserve a "toggled" state) to control whether the item is expanded or not.

Comment: Hmm how have I been here for a decade and not seen this design stuff before‽ I’d still assume that someone meant to make it a filled button; I can see a transparent button’s value in some situations like as a cancel button next to a primary button, but it makes no sense just existing on its own.

Comment: Stacks has only been a thing for the past few years, I think 2-3 , so "How I have been here a decade and" ... you can't see what's not there